# query.getResultList is slower than query.list

Tags: hibernate

My table is properly indexed and for a simple select query using indexed value, I have noticed that query.getResultList() is taking more time (approximately 5 seconds) to fetch results. I tried using query.list() and result is coming in less than 10milliseconds.

I did not see any difference in result/output of both queries, both are same.

Can someone help me understand if there is any difference in data extraction using above two methods.

[image]As you can see from the attachment, I'm observing a difference in time but result is same.

Comment: It looks like cache , try to execute the queries in reverse order.

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: Any suggestion on why it is taking more time. I'm using spring JPA and database-PostgreSQL.
If I execute query in editor, data is coming in 10millisec.

Comment: Try to have hibernate log the query, and see what it looks like.

Comment: I found problem with entity having OneToOne mapping for several columns creating multiple queries internally by Hibernate. I will correct this.